# How to upload an XML object and save it with Perl on the server?

Tags: javascript, xml, perl, upload, xmlhttprequest

I have tried various versions now, but I simply seem to miss something.
Funnily I haven't found an example for this so far.
Only thing seems to be uploaded by my Javascript is `[object XMLDocument]`.
(I try to save the XML-Document in the receiving perl-script, and that's the string that the perl script writes to the outputfile.)

For the JavaScript part I looked at [Mozilla's *Using FormData Objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects).

And then came up with:

```
function httpPerlUploadBigData(fuPerlTarget, contentToWrite, fuCallMeOnLoad) {

  var formData = new FormData();
  var blob = new Blob([contentToWrite], { type: "text/xml"});

  formData.append('file', blob, "filename.txt");
  formData.append('bigcontent', contentToWrite);
  formData.append('saveOnServerAs', 'temp.xml');

  var MyThis = this;
  this.perlTarget = fuPerlTarget;
  this.callMeOnLoad = fuCallMeOnLoad;

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", MyThis.perlTarget, true);
  oReq.onload = function(e) {
    MyThis.callMeOnLoad( e.target.response );
  };

  oReq.send(formData);
}
```

I send `contentToWrite` twice because I would like to upload it in a way that the script sees as an uploaded file. The other code I tried before uploaded it as plain text, but because this is XML I guess an upload as sort of file would be better.

Answer (score 3):

`contentToWrite` seems to contain an `XMLDocument` object. The [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) accepts an `Array` of `ArrayBuffer`, `ArrayBufferView`, `Blob`, `DOMString` objects. So you must [serialize the XML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML#Part_2.3A_how_to_serialize_the_content_of_a_given_XML_document) first:

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var xmlString  = serializer.serializeToString(contentToWrite);
var blob       = new Blob([ xmlString ], { type: "text/xml"});
```